# Javascript - Insert onClick function dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

My index.html

```
<div id="dropDownBolumDiv" class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(0px, 38px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">

</div>

<script>
     var parameterYil = document.getElementById("dropDownYil1").value;
     var bolumler = ["ELEME MAKİNALARI", "ELEVATÖR", "EXCELL", "FOTOSORTER"];
     for (i = 0; i < bolumler.length; i++) {
         $("#dropDownBolumDiv").append("<a class='dropdown-item' onclick='refreshCharts(parameterYil,"+bolumler[i]+")'>" + bolumler[i] + "</a>");
     }
</script>
```

For example : when I clicked EXCELL,nothing happen.And console error says;

> Uncaught ReferenceError: EXCELL is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

What is problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap bolumler's units in single quotes(') to make them string, not identifier

```
bolumler.forEach(v => {
         $("#dropDownBolumDiv").append(`<a class='dropdown-item' onclick='refreshCharts(parameterYil,"${v}")'>${v}</a>`);
     })
```

Comment: I changed and result : `<a class="dropdown-item" onclick="refreshCharts(2019," eleme  makİnalari')'>ELEME MAKİNALARI</a>` so dont work

Comment: Then just use not a single qoute but double qoutes with \ before it

refreshCharts(parameterYil,\""+bolumler[i]+"\")

Comment: sorry, I changed my answer, i checked - this way it works

Comment: don't work but no problem.
I'll still mark it as an answer.Thank you..